# Laravel: How to specify screen when error validation

Tags: validation, laravel, input, screen

I validate input data by write method rules() in Request class,

```
class AAARequest extends Request
{
    public function rules()
    {
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

And I have Controller code:

```
class AAAController extends Controller
{
    public function add()
    {
        .....
        .....
    }

    public function addConfirm(AAARequest $request)
    {
        .....
        .....
    }

    public function addSave(AAARequest $request)
    {
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

My flow:

ADD screen -> submit -> validate input data

1. OK: go to CONFIRM screen
2. NG: show error message at ADD screen

CONFIRM screen -> submit -> validate input data

1. OK: go to SAVE screen
2. NG: show error message ad ADD screen

But because use validation by Request class. So, when from CONFIRM screen submit to SAVE screen. If validation fail, Laravel auto repsonse back to CONFIRM screen.

But, I want back to ADD screen. How can I config to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In your AAARequest you can define `$redirect = 'path/to/add-form'` property and the validator will redirect you to that page if validation fails.

There's an alternative, you can define `redirectRoute` or `redirectAction` properties if you don't want to mess with string paths.

You can dig into this code if you want more details: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php

Comment: You don't understand me. My question is not keep input data. My question is how to customize Request class for specify destination when got error validation.